# How do you say in castellano/Spanish "Jump on one leg"?

Tags: expresiones, expresiones-fijas

How do you say in imperative form that someone should jump on one leg?

Is it:

- Da **brincos en** una pierna
- Da **brincos de** una pierna
- Da **saltos en** una pierna

Or is it totally different? How?

Comment: _Saltar a la pata coja_

Comment: Do you want the translation or the coloquial meaning? 1 and 3 are the same and correct translations. I can imagine there is a children game "pata coja" but that may depend on different country.

Comment: I have noticed that many of the other answers include _saltar_ **en** _una pierna_ as correct. It isn't, at least, in Spain. As some have pointed, you should use _saltar/brincar_ **con** _una pierna_, **sobre** _una pierna_, or _a la pata coja_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does anybody read the part of the question that says "imperative form"? I am from Madrid and in an "imperative from", I would say depending on how many people the message is sent to:

- Only one person: "Tú" (any of the next options is fine):

a)  Salta sobre una (sola) pierna.

a1) Da saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

b) Salta con una (sola) pierna.

b1) Da saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

c) Salta a la pata coja.

c1) Da saltos a la pata coja.

- Only one person: "Usted" (This is the polite/very respectful way of "Tú". For example we use "Usted" when talking to an old person or one of your customers in your job). The three previous options would be now:

a) Salte sobre una (sola) pierna.

a1) De saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

b) Salte con una (sola) pierna.

b1) De saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

c) Salte a la pata coja.

c1) De saltos a la pata coja.

- More than one person: "Vosotros" (The plural of "Tú". See the "d"):

a) Salta**d** sobre una (sola) pierna.

a1) Da**d** saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

b) Salta**d** con una (sola) pierna.

b2) Da**d** saltos con una (sola) pierna.

c) Salta**d** a la pata coja.

c2) Da**d** saltos a la pata coja.

- More than one person: "Ustedes" (The plural of "Usted". See the "n")

a) Salte**n** sobre una (sola) pierna.

a1) De**n** saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

b) Salte**n** con una (sola) pierna.

b1) De**n** saltos sobre una (sola) pierna.

c) Salte**n** a la pata coja.

c1) De**n** saltos a la pata coja.

Here are some notes about the previous sentences:

- The word "solo" is optional but i would include it to emphasise that it is "one" leg. You can use before or after "pierna" (In the previous sentences I included before, but after is ok too: for example, "Salta sobre una pierna sola")
- You can use the verb "Saltar" or "Dar saltos". The meaning is the same. A synonym of "Saltar" is "Brincar" (or "Dar brincos") I have not included these options to avoid making this post longer, however the conjugation is the same than in the case of "saltar" [If you want, I can write them all]
- As Héctor E said before, I would not use "en" for linking the verb "saltar" to the number of legs you are using to jump. For me, the correct prepositions in this case are "sobre" or "con" [Saltar sobre una pierna | Saltar con una pierna |Saltar sobre las dos piernas |Saltar con las dos piernas-]. I do not know if it is ok in any other country (different from Spain), but for me it sounds, at least, estrange. A different point here is the use of "en" if you are saying **where** you are jumping on (for example "Saltar con una sola pierna en la calle" or "Saltar en el campo con las dos piernas". The place where you are jumping on is the street -or the countryside-)
- As somebody told you before "Saltar a la pata coja" is an informal way of saying "jumping on one leg". The context where you would hear it more often is in chidren plays.

Comment: "Does anybody read the part of the question that says "imperative form"?" Yes, but as I told [Angelo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13547/5481), the OP is using imperative tense correctly in every example in his question. I don't think he has a problem with imperative tense, but with the verb he needs to use after "dar" (saltar/brincar - en/de una pierna). I bet that he could conjugate correctly imperative for _saltar_ and _brincar_. Nevertheless, +1 really complete answer.

Answer (score 8):

"Jumping on one leg", (or "hopping on one leg) at least in Castilian Spanish would be `Saltar a la pata coja`

[Pata](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=pata) would refer to the leg of an animal or object, like a chair. [Cojo/ja](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=EXk7nSHRRDXX218zrRFA) is someone or something with a missing leg.

> Los niños estaban jugando a este juego de **saltar a la pata coja** hasta el cuadro con la piedra, recogerla y regresar.  <sub>The kids were playing this game of stepping on one feet to the place the stone is, collects it and coming back.</sub>

Comment: En argentina es sólo "saltar en una pata"

Answer (score 6):

Brincar y saltar son sinónimos, así que *saltar con una pierna* y *brincar con una pierna* son correctos, también le puedes indicar a alguien que de *brincos con una pierna* o *de saltos con una pierna*

Comment: I think this is the most neutral way to say it.

Comment: Not everywhere.

Comment: Try to complete your answer to make it more apt for the global hispanic World. Other than that welcome to SL&U!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the question, it says `imperative form`. So I think it should be `Salta en una pierna` or `Brinca en una pierna`

Comment: Despite the title, reading the question and seeing its tags I don't think that the OP has a question about verb tenses. His question is about the expression for "jumping in one leg". He is even using imperative of "dar" correctly in each of his examples.